# SET Directory php mkdir

Tags: php, windows, macos, mkdir

I want to create a directory where I will be saving all downloaded images. But not sure if we have a solution that will work on MAC and Windows.

Is there some kind of method to do this?

Comment: PHP is PHP, it doesn't matter which operating system you're using, just as long as PHP is installed and properly configured and that the folders have proper permissions set to write to. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: ow right.. thanks for clearing that out. :)